# How do I install gradle offline on android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-3.0

The gradle version under project structure is 4.1 so I tried to direct the IDE to the directory where I had extracted the .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download the gradle-4.1-bin.zip.
2.Now extract and paste it in the C:\Users\username.gradle directory.
3.Enable offline work in (Preferences -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings -> Offline work)

Comment: By the way do I use the 'Use local gradle option' or just the default?

Comment: Use local gradle distribution.set Gradle home to your extracted Gradle directory.

Comment: Which directory do I point it to because when I try with the .zip it won't build.

Comment: Extract and copy

Comment: I just did that and tried to build but the gradle sync failed and it's giving me a couple of dependency errors in the build.gradle file.

Comment: Hey I ended up syncing online.

Comment: Has anyone used the Learn Android Studio but Adam Gerber? Having trouble in chapter 5.